# Scala: recursion and stack overflow error

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow, numerical-integration

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

*Define a recursive function* inteDef *that approximates the definite integral of a function* f *on the interval* [a,b] *using the composite trapezoidal rule. The function will take* eps *as a parameter, which marks the maximum length of the subintervals into which the interval* [a,b] *will be divided. Thus, if the length of* [a,b] *is less than or equal to* eps, *the function will return the
area of the corresponding trapezoid. Otherwise, it will divide the interval* [a,b] *into two subintervals of the same length (half of the original interval) and it will recursively approximate the integral of both intervals and return their sum.*

My solution attempt is:

```scala
def inteDef(f: Double => Double, x: Double, y: Double, eps: Double): Double = {
  if (abs(y - x) <= eps)
    (y - x) * (f(x) + f(y)) / 2.0
  else
    inteDef(f, x, (y-x)/2.0, eps) + inteDef(f, (y-x)/2.0, y, eps)
  }
```

It works when *eps* is greater than or equal to *abs(y - x)*, but gives a stack overflow error otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(y - x) / 2.0` is not in the middle between `x` and `y`.

`(x + y) / 2.0` is.